Appium not getting started, getting error -org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message:"
Trying to run my first Appium java code.
appium --version
2.11.5  - Up and running in CLI
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
 cap.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
 cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "13");
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "realme 9 bk")

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.151:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

======
dependencies added in POM.xml:
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
   
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>

tried above code.
getting exception :
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource 

===================================


Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:automationName=UiAutomator2, browserName=Chrome, appium:deviceName=realme 9 bk, platformName=ANDROID, appium:platformVersion=13, appium:udid=JZLNVKXWWOPNZDF6}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: Chrome, deviceName: realme 9 bk, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13, udid: JZLNVKXWWOPNZDF6}}]
Capabilities {automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: Chrome, deviceName: realme 9 bk, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13, udid: JZLNVKXWWOPNZDF6}


Also showing -URL  @Deprecated(since="20")
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.151:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
**Tried everything from my end, please help.
**
though Appium is up and running, ADB device is connected.
